# Saving the user's oauth keys in a cookie

Tags: php, cookies, twitter, oauth

I use oauth to connect my web app to twitter. It works fine, but I need to re-authorise the application regularly.

I save the keys in the session, but this seems to get wiped out when the users closes the page.

Should I save the keys in an additional cookie ?

```
function access_token($tmhOAuth) {
  $tmhOAuth->config['user_token']  = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token'];
  $tmhOAuth->config['user_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth']['oauth_token_secret'];

  $code = $tmhOAuth->request(
    'POST',
    $tmhOAuth->url('oauth/access_token', ''),
    array(
      'oauth_verifier' => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']
    )
  );

  if ($code == 200) {
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $tmhOAuth->extract_params($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
    unset($_SESSION['oauth']);
    header('Location: ' . tmhUtilities::php_self());
  } else {
    outputError($tmhOAuth);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the keys in a cookie, making sure you set the cookie expiry for a long enough time, or store them for as long as you want in a persistent database.